# How to code a common JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I want to code a common JavaScript module which can be used in Node.js, Web. So it should support *import*, *require* and standalone use after **Webpack** or **Browserify** with **Babel** compiling.

For example, this module could use *require* in Node.js or use *import*/*require* in other project source code or use `<script>` to import it directly in web.

Who can help me or provide some links for references.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use require/import for client side code in HTML. Then require/import will not work. You can use "Bower" for that. Check this -

https://bower.io/

Install the package using bower command then you can simply use that package by loading it into script.Like -

```
<script>package_name</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty difficult to write commonJS module which can't be used in node.js and in browser (most of generic npm modules are like this). All you have to do is to avoid browser-only and node-only features (or use browserify). If you use ES2015, you can also avoid using babel because there is no reason for it.

You can use linter like ESLint and set environmental options to both browser and node.js - it should help you avoid extra dependencies.